# BeautifulSoup returns None among valid results

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

BeautifulSoup returns `None` several among valid results, which are the movie titles. Here's my code:

```
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
url="https://www.rogerebert.com/balder-and-dash/the-best-films-of-the-2010s"
soup=BeautifulSoup(urlopen(url), "html.parser")

tags=soup.find_all("strong")
for tag in tags:
    title=tag.find("a")
    print(title)
```

How can I ensure that `None` doesn't show up? I've tried `lxml` parser as well as Selenium but I'm getting the same results. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO! What are you trying to output exactly? The problem is some `<strong>` tags have no `<a>` child. If you want `<strong>`s that have an `<a>` child, you could do `[x.parent for x in soup.select("strong > a")]`.

Comment: Just add an `if title:` prior to `print(title)`.

Comment: some `<strong>` doesn't have `<a>`  so it returns `None`

Comment: @baglenta You might want to make this a question that could be helpful to more people, like saying: `How to remove None from BeautifulSoup output` and then leaving your problem as the example.

Comment: That depends on what you mean by _doesn’t show up_, can you be more specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of just `print(title)`, qualify it with an `if` statement:

```
if title:
    print(title)
```

This means that a `None` will equate to `if False` and will not print.

Edit: To get just the titles and cut out the surrounding anchor tags you also put `print(title.text)`. Thanks to BeastCoder for suggesting this.

Comment: Great answer! Might want to add `title.text` though

Answer (score 0):

per @ggorlen's comment above, if you just want to print the titles:

```
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
url="https://www.rogerebert.com/balder-and-dash/the-best-films-of-the-2010s"
soup=BeautifulSoup(urlopen(url), "html.parser")

tags=soup.select("strong > a")
for tag in tags:
    print(tag.text)
```